meta-ros: sdk do_fetch sig is different
When extracting the the sdk shell script I have these warnings:
WARNING: The libxml-parser-perl-native:do_fetch sig is computed to be a221f5dddf0ec82b2cff9656f6facb20343c0459c350b423e7ec75b0bb2e7c8f, but the sig is locked to 659a637560707da23674f1ec157806dc2ae3d951afed1e870d3bcdf1b1b0bbf1 in SIGGEN_LOCKEDSIGS_t-x86-64
The shadow-securetty:do_fetch sig is computed to be c3035c42eea4f08b4d63aac529590e33759ff2284d6e15b2c25d4bc02822f6e8, but the sig is locked to a6e89633c3cda05df1153b3e190983d11551a8b8d60d917c627397fe01fb0b3a in SIGGEN_LOCKEDSIGS_t-raspberrypi4-64
The systemd-systemctl-native:do_fetch sig is computed to be 86bd43715c8d6001ab8e2b6011b19adcd08e147158260c35341f6bc50924ff33, but the sig is locked to 163c435ec206fdf25bd61da40a2c6d7cc85167eb7876463ac4f628c6c8332404 in SIGGEN_LOCKEDSIGS_t-x86-64
The connman-conf:do_fetch sig is computed to be f44c97279e18c51bfba4b86b12aa2ef25962baf2627911586a575c59a8b3aa05, but the sig is locked to 9c8224a9dda9ff5f1c6fa412271f8e2c3274a566c04ae0e66725193d36638343 in SIGGEN_LOCKEDSIGS_t-raspberrypi4-64
The systemd-conf:do_fetch sig is computed to be 425c9589f7828183397b368431a6ee7dfa01c7236a5726af6b671229c3c0e4c2, but the sig is locked to 7855216876e3855f8a6985c5ed1c44d114af9f86554be17e483d3d75c2a04f1d in SIGGEN_LOCKEDSIGS_t-raspberrypi4-64
The systemd-serialgetty:do_fetch sig is computed to be 357c69170b2a116b45972ec160e1bc78a5079ee31c01970112545f50687cfd1f, but the sig is locked to 87c156f0976f22f97644a642c3a92197bbcbece9f9ae5e435b65588390ace27b in SIGGEN_LOCKEDSIGS_t-raspberrypi4-64
The run-postinsts:do_fetch sig is computed to be 653cb8b7a7e3c43071ef575bfef44f70b9905a9d93209c45a580d97f4817f495, but the sig is locked to 692760434269fbf48cf9e307a370e9ba0fad8baeb41335ccca5d415b11ffe132 in SIGGEN_LOCKEDSIGS_t-allarch

The sdk sh script is generated with:
kas build kas/oeros-scarthgap-jazzy-raspberrypi4-64.yml

I assume the *-conf and run-postinsts are rather fine.
But I'm wondering why the hash of libxml-parser-perl-native could be different?
